# On a sum like Kloosterman sum

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sums

I encounter a tricky sum like the Kloosterman sum

$$\sum_{x \mod qP} e ( \frac{x+\overline{x+P}}{qP} ),$$
where $q$ is a positive integer, $P$ is a prime number satisfying $(q,P)=1$, $x \bmod qP,(x,qP)=1,$ $ \overline{x} $ means $ x\overline{x} \equiv 1\pmod {qP}$.

If this sum can be bounded by $O((qP)^{1/2+\varepsilon}$) by invoking Weil bound for Kloosterman sums? Did anyone ever saw this kind of sum before?Please share some comments. Many thanks.

My confusions are as follows:
(a) One may try to split the sum into two sums with the modulos being $q$ and $P$. However we may have the issue that $y+1$ is not co-prime with $q$ when writing $qP=xq+yP$ with $x \bmod P,(x,P)=1,$ and $y \bmod q,(y,q)=1.$ So that it seems that one cannot write $\overline{xq+(y+1)P}\mod {qP}$ as the form $x\cdot A+y\cdot B$ for some integers $A,B$.

(b) For typical modulos, for example, to consider the sum $$\sum_{x \mod c} e ( \frac{x+\overline{x+P}}{c} ),$$
where $c$ is an arbitrary positive integer. If we have the square-root cancellation for this type of sum, just like the Wiel bound?

Your any opinions are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in the case $y+1$ not coprime with $q$, the problem is not that we cannot right the inverse in that form - the problem is that the inverse does not exist! What do you want that term in the sum to be then? Zero?

Comment: If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

As Will Sawin pointed out, it is not clear what you mean by $\overline{x+P}$ when $x+P$ is not coprime to $qP$ (i.e. when $x+P$ is not coprime to $q$). If you omit these terms and you assume that $q$ is square-free, then you do get a Weil-like bound by Proposition 4.6 in Polymath's paper New equidistribution estimates of Zhang type, Algebra & Number Theory 8 (2014), 2067-2199. This is also Proposition 4.6 in the latest [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.0811).

Comment: @Will Sawin,GH from MO

Comment: @Fei: You addressed something to Will and to me in the previous comment, but the message is empty. If you just wanted to say thanks, then please say thanks for clarity.

Comment: @Will Sawin,GH from MO Great thanks to Will Sawin for pointing out the blur. Notice  $\overline{x+P}$, one does not have the case that  $y+1$ not coprime with $q$. Also great thanks to GH from MO for guiding the reference. Write $x=x_1q+ x_2 P$ with $x_1 \bmod P, (x_1,P)=1$ and $x_2\bmod q, (x_2,q)=1$. We have
 \[\overline{(x+P)}  \equiv \overline{ (P+x_1q)q}q + \overline{ (P+x_2 P)P }P  \pmod {qP}$$. Hence by the Chinese Remainder Theorem one may write the sum we concerned about as a product of two sums of  the modulos being $q$ and $P$ respectively.

Comment: Sorry, I  just editting the messege but worongly press the Enter .